# Download file with AjaxLazyLoadPanel

Tags: java, wicket

Idea of the code below is to show download dialog in browser when lazy loaded panel is loaded.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.wicket.Component;
import org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLazyLoadPanel;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.EmptyPanel;
import org.apache.wicket.request.handler.resource.ResourceStreamRequestHandler;
import org.apache.wicket.request.resource.ContentDisposition;
import org.apache.wicket.util.resource.AbstractResourceStreamWriter;

public class LazyLoadedPage extends WebPage {

    public LazyLoadedPage() {
        add(new Label("text", "waiting..."));
        add(new AjaxLazyLoadPanel("lazy") {

            @Override
            public Component getLazyLoadComponent(final String id) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                final ResourceStreamRequestHandler handler = new ResourceStreamRequestHandler(new Resource(),
                        "test2.txt");
//                handler.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.ATTACHMENT);
                getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(handler);
                return new EmptyPanel(id);
            }
        });
    }

    class Resource extends AbstractResourceStreamWriter {

        @Override
        public void write(final OutputStream output) throws IOException {
            final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", "txt");
            final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
            fos.write("text".getBytes());
            fos.close();

            final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            final byte[] buff = new byte[10];
            final int cnt = fis.read(buff);
            output.write(buff, 0, cnt);
        }

    }

}
```

But when I try it I get this error in Wicket Ajax debug window:

```
ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Error: Invalid XML: text
```

How can I fix my code (probably using another approach)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used [AJAXDownload](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow) from Apache wiki.